# Broken CURL and can't fix it

Tags: json, linux, http, curl

I am trying to run this curl on Linux Ubuntu but the maybe I am using wrong syntax. This is the content of my .sh file. Please help:

```
curl --request POST \
  --url http://example.com/service1 \
  --header 'content-type: application/json' \
  --data '{\r\n "myId": 211122285,\r\n "key2": {\r\n  "ENABLE_MY_PROPERTY": "1"\r\n }\r\n}'
```

Do you know what is wrong with it. It is saying that:

***{"code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"[line: 1, column: 3] Unexpected character ('\' (code 92)): was expecting double-quote to start field name\n at...*** etc.

Comment: Here is a good link to answer your question: https://superuser.com/questions/149329/what-is-the-curl-command-line-syntax-to-do-a-post-request

Comment: you can get rid of those \r\n's at least.

Comment: @hanshenrik - Be careful about *not* using CRLF in web protocols. The HTTP RFC specifically uses them. Linux LF and OS X CR are not the end-of-line marker in the RFC.

Comment: @saferJo - Regarding ***`line: 1, column: 3`***, isn't that your shebang? It sounds like you used `#!\bin\env bash` rather than `#!/bin/env bash` or similar.

Comment: @jww sure, but this is not about the HTTP headers, this is about the http post body, which is a json. and those \r\n's are just plain insignificant whitespace to json.

Comment: solved it thanks to the comment of jww - to delete the "\r\n". But still dont know why the linux dont understand them. Btw even jww did not interpred the response. Now I am watching it again and it is saying  "code":"BAD_REQUEST","message":"[line: 1, column: 3] . It is clear that this is the response of the server. The server is not familiar with the whole curl with my structure- for the server line 1 column 3 means: line 1 from the body of the request, but not for my curl file... how stupid I am... now it is working perfect

Comment: also these scripts can run without such first liners "#!/bin/env"

Comment: Sorry hanshenrik told the answer

Comment: lol yes sorry yes it is @hanshenrik

Comment: i suspect its not about curl at all, there's something wrong with the json you try to send

Comment: it was not able to parse these "\r\n".

Comment: [line: 1, column: 3] is the symbol \